# split list values from openpyxl output in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am working with openpyxl in python to pull specific column data which has comma separated values in few cells. Output i get 'CVE-2021-1111, CVE-2021'.  The output required is 'CVE-2021-1111', 'CVE-2021'.

Please help me

Input from excel column:(large data truncated here)
CVE-2017-12652
CVE-2020-12243
CVE-2019-14866
CVE-2019-16935
CVE-2019-17493
CVE-2021-1111, CVE-2021

---

from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

senior = load_workbook("C:\senior.xlsx")
sr = senior.active

range1 = sr['B2':'B15']
csv1 = []
for names in range1:
for cell in names:
if cell.value != None:
csv1.append(cell.value)
print(csv1)

Output i get:
['CVE-2017-12652', 'CVE-2020-12243', 'CVE-2019-14866', 'CVE-2019-16935', 'CVE-2019-17493', 'CVE-2021-1111, CVE-2021']

Required output (last 2 values should be split)
['CVE-2017-12652', 'CVE-2020-12243', 'CVE-2019-14866', 'CVE-2019-16935', 'CVE-2019-17493', 'CVE-2021-1111', 'CVE-2021']

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, you will need to split the `cell.value` by the expected commas. Also you can remove the spaces in the strings before appending to `csv1` to return the required output.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

senior = load_workbook("C:\senior.xlsx")
sr = senior.active

range1 = sr['B2':'B15'] 

csv1 = []

for names in range1:
    for cell in names:
        if cell.value != None:
            cell_value = cell.value.replace(' ', '').split(',')
            csv1 += cell_value if isinstance(cell_value, list) else [cell_value]
```

EDIT: Based on the comment I added a simpler version, instead of filling csv1 in one line.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

senior = load_workbook("C:\senior.xlsx")
sr = senior.active

range1 = sr['B2':'B15'] 

csv1 = []

for names in range1:
    for cell in names:
        if cell.value != None:
            cell_value = cell.value.replace(' ', '').split(',')
            if isinstance(cell_value, list):
                csv1 += cell_value
            else:
                csv1.append(cell_value)
```

Comment: It perfectly worked. Thank you Karim. Could you please help me understand what the below two lines does         
cell.value.replace(' ', '').split(',')   
cell_value if isinstance(cell_value, list) else [cell_value]

Comment: Sure.  so this line `cell_value = cell.value.replace(' ', '').split(',')` remove the spaces and then it splits the string by the commas into multiple strings in a list. Then this line `csv1 += cell_value if isinstance(cell_value, list) else [cell_value]` uses the `+=` operator to append list elements in a list

Comment: I have edited a simpler version to clarify the answer. This `csv1 += cell_value if isinstance(cell_value, list) else [cell_value]` line was wrote in that way to avoid having 4 lines of code doing the same thing. But I hope the EDIT in the answer clarify what was done.